# What is the minimum OS version and swift language version to be used for new apps in App Store?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

If I'm developing a new app what is the minimum OS version and swift language version to be used ??

Comment: You can check this : https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/354421

Comment: Best practice for new apps is support 3 iOS versions, so, for now you need to support iOS 12 - 14. If you want to use SwiftUI, you need to setup iOS 13. Swift version for this iOS could be newest (Swift 5.5)

Comment: You need to use the iOS 14 SDK. You can support as old a version as you like, but personally I would probably target iOS 13 or even iOS 14 as a minimum if I was making a new app now, depending on the features I wanted to use. iOS 14 is probably more than 98% of devices.

Answer (score 2):

Aside of requirements, there  is a difference between what is suggested and what is possible.

Required is:
You need to use Xcode 12.
https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=ib31uj1j

Possible is:
Support iOS 9, as it is currently the lowest target you can select with Xcode 12.

Suggested is:
Support iOS 13 or higher, as this run on 93% of all devices recently seen on the app store.
https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/

As for Swift
Swift 5.3 was comming with Xcode 12 and default for new project. However was Swift 4x still compiling back then. Didnt try this recently as there is no point or advantages from using an old language version. In fact you need to write way more boilerplate code if you stick with Swift 4.